# Smooth centering on current location in WP8 maps

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, maps

I have a feeling this question has already been asked here at stackoverflow, but I just can't find anything for the life of me...

I have a map control in a Windows Phone 8 app, that (among other things) shows my current location. I also have a button, that lets me focus the map back on my current location, if I scroll it to some place else. The problem is: tapping it makes the map "teleport" to the current location, unlike the standard HERE Maps, where you get a smooth scroll through the map.
So my question is: HOW do you do that? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the `SetView` API? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207930(v=vs.105).aspx

Use the `Linear` or `Parabolic` animation.